# How to get total number of users in slack team

Tags: slack, slack-api

Currently the only way I can find is to iterate over the `users.list` endpoint, but I think this isn't an efficient way to do it, I expected to find an attribute `number_of_users` in the `team.info` endpoint.
Any suggestions for a better way to get the total number of users ?

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to get the total numer of you users is with the `user.list` endpoint.

But I don't think there is any need to iterate through the list by yourself. You get an array from the endpoint, so you can just do a count on it.

e.g. in PHP you something like:
`$memberCount = count($userlist['members']);`

Comment: It's mentioned in the api that the list will be truncated at 1500 user soon

Comment: yes, but as I understand that only affects the conversation related methods, but not `users.list`
https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-10-members-array-truncating

Comment: This approach is also not compatible with paging via the `&limit=x` query param. If you have to make multiple requests to `users.list` then a simple `count()` will not suffice. It would definitely be nice to have an attribute returned from `team.info` or `users.list` with the total user count.